# Will rendering on a second GPU leave rest of the system (mostly) idle?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

we need some longer Cycles Renderwork to be done an found that buying a second GPU is probably a lot cheaper than renting render nodes in the cloud. We're talking about weeks of render time.

The question is: **Can we equip one of our workstations with a second GPU, have Cycles render ONLY on that second GPU and leave the rest of the system free for some other heavy tasks, like video editing?**
I mean some CPU peaks here and there and some memory and disk usage are totally ok - blocking the CPU with 50%-100% of usage is not.

Rest of the system is a Ryzen 7 1800x with 32GB of RAM and primary GPU is the GTX 1080

Can someone who has 2 GPUs please render a benchmark on only the second GPU and give some stats about the rest of the system usage?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The CPU is not idle when rendering in GPU. Rendering while doing something else will result in a slowdown, both for the rendering process and for other tasks in the computer, especially video editing, which is  resource intensive. If you want to do that, consider using a second computer with just to render. It doesn't have to be quite as powerful, as most of the work will be done by the GPU.

Comment: I know that. It would still be great to get a "feel" for what I could expect when doing it that way. A few simple screenshots of Windows taskmanager would be sufficient to answer the question.